# Flexbox - A nested parent div does not expand when its content is scrollable

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a problem with the flexbox when a parent does not expand with its content and styling consequently is also not applied. I have the following structure:

```css
.first {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.second {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap; /*Forcing items to expand the parent*/
  flex: 0 1 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.second div {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div class="second">
    <div>Item 1</div>
    <div>Item 2</div>
    <div>Item 3</div>
    <div>Item 4</div>
    <div>Item 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It scrolls the second div nicely as items expand this div, but I want to make the first div to scroll instead. So, if I disable scrolling on the second div with `overflow-x: unset` and move the scrolling to the first div `overflow-x: scroll`, it scrolls nicely as well, but the second div appears not to be expanded with its content, and the styling is also not applied to the overflowing area.

The reason I need to move a scrollbar one level up is, I will have one more div under the first div, which will be also scrollable, and I want both second level divs to scroll horizontally with a shared scrollbar (so it is like a table). Can someone please help with how to expand the second level div to the parent's width?